# How to filter object using some array?

Tags: javascript

I have to filter the object based on the values of array.

This is my object

```
$scope.myObj = {
    en_US: "English",
    es_ES: "Spanish",
    pt_PT: "Portuguese",
    fr_FR: "French",
    de_DE: "German"
}
```

This is my array

```
$scope.myArr=["en_US","es_ES"]
```

I want to filter my object using my array? How to do that in efficient way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: get the keys and match

Comment: What do you mean by *filter*? 1. You want to map your array from codes to names? 2. You want to reduce your object to only include properties that match those in the array? 3. Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the given keys and build a new object.

```js
var $scope = {}, result;

$scope.myObj = { en_US: "English", es_ES: "Spanish", pt_PT: "Portuguese", fr_FR: "French", de_DE: "German" };
$scope.myArr = ["en_US", "es_ES"];

result = $scope.myArr.reduce(function (o, k) {
    o[k] = $scope.myObj[k];
    return o;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

ES6 with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var $scope = {}, result;

$scope.myObj = { en_US: "English", es_ES: "Spanish", pt_PT: "Portuguese", fr_FR: "French", de_DE: "German" };
$scope.myArr = ["en_US", "es_ES"];

result = $scope.myArr.reduce((o, k) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: $scope.myObj[k] }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Even shorter with ES6, [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var $scope = {}, result;

$scope.myObj = { en_US: "English", es_ES: "Spanish", pt_PT: "Portuguese", fr_FR: "French", de_DE: "German" };
$scope.myArr = ["en_US", "es_ES"];

result = Object.assign(...$scope.myArr.map(k => ({ [k]: $scope.myObj[k] })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to get the desired result.

```js
var myObj = {en_US: "English", es_ES: "Spanish", pt_PT: "Portuguese", fr_FR: "French", de_DE: "German"},
    myArr = ["en_US","es_ES"];
    
    myObj = Object.keys(myObj).reduce(function(s,a) {
      if (myArr.indexOf(a) == -1) {
        s[a] = myObj[a];
      }
      return s;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to be using AngularJS you can use the [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function:

```js
var myObj = {
  en_US: "English",
  es_ES: "Spanish",
  pt_PT: "Portuguese",
  fr_FR: "French",
  de_DE: "German"
};

var myArr = ["en_US", "es_ES"];

angular.forEach(myObj, function(value, key) {

  // if the key doesn't appear in `myArr` delete the key-pair from the object
  if (myArr.indexOf(key) === -1) {

    // delete the property from the object
    delete myObj[key];

  }

});

console.log(myObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.filter() function like

```
myArr.filter(function (o, k) {
o[k] = myObj[k];
return o;
}, {});
```

This will give result like [0:"en_US",1:"es_ES"]

refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for more information

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking to match those ISO language codes found in `myArr` against `myObj`. Hence, `Array.prototype.map` should be enough:

```js
var myArr = ["en_US", "es_ES"];

var myObj = {
  en_US: "English",
  es_ES: "Spanish",
  pt_PT: "Portuguese",
  fr_FR: "French",
  de_DE: "German"
};

var matchedLangs = myArr.map(lang => ({
  [lang]: myObj[lang]
}));

console.log(matchedLangs);
```

This approach will give you an array of objects where properties are the ISO language codes and the property values their English name.

If you're looking for an object result, let's add `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var myArr = ["en_US", "es_ES"];

var myObj = {
  en_US: "English",
  es_ES: "Spanish",
  pt_PT: "Portuguese",
  fr_FR: "French",
  de_DE: "German"
};

// #1 Array.prototype.map returns an array of matched language codes to 
// their english names
// 
// #2 Array.prototype.reduce receives the array from #1 and transforms it
// creating a new "result" object. Object.assign mixes the "match" object 
// (an object whose property is the ISO code and the value the English name)
// with the "result" object, which represents the accumulated result
var matchedLangs = myArr.map(lang => ({
  [lang]: myObj[lang]
})).reduce((result, match) => Object.assign(result, match));

console.log(matchedLangs);

// Everything can be also be simplified to just use Array.prototype.reduce:
var matchedLangs2 = myArr.reduce((result, lang) =>
  Object.assign(result, {
    [lang]: myObj[lang]
  }), {});

console.log(matchedLangs2);
```

### What's the `{ [blah]: "x" }` thing?

Since ECMA-Script 2015, you can declare properties using non-literal values.

See the following snippet:

```js
var propertyName = "hello";

var obj = { [propertyName]: "world" };

console.log(obj);
```